# How do I debug using MVC in VS 2013?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5/EF app that I can't seem to debug at all. I have a console app also in the project that I can debug just fine, but when I set a breakpoint in a controller it won't debug. I've googled this but can't find anything that can help.

Comment: So the application runs? From Visual Studio? Maybe the controller just doesn't get hit?

Comment: Yes - it runs from Visual Studio. I know that the code is being hit because I'm setting a Viewbag value that I then reference in the page.

Answer (score 0):

MVC 5 and EF most certainly works in debug.  It even debugs jquery.  So you must have something not right.

I would check all the projects build debug settings.  Make sure build mode is debug.
Add some breakpoints early on to see if they are getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to pin point the exact problem considering we can’t see your project’s solution.

But for the record, you mention that you have **both** an ASP.NET MVC application **AND** a Console application living within the **same** project.

Since you’re also saying that you can debug the console application, could it be that the Console application is the one that is Set as StartUp project and NOT the MVC application?

If that’s not the case, can you tell us which of your projects is Set as StartUp Project?

Comment: I just created a new solution that doesn't contain a console app and for simplicity sake I moved all of the classes into the root project (they were in separate projects called Model and Repository. Still nothing. I set a breakpoint in the HomeController in the Search action (and various other breakpoints throughout the app) and nothing gets hit! It's a very simple app with just a handful of views/models/controllers.

Comment: This is strange...How about trying to attach to process? Set a breakpoint on the Index() method of your HomeController. Debug-->Attach to process…and find your w3wp.exe

Comment: There is no w3wp.exe process in my list of processes. That's odd - there should be - right? Any idea why this could be missing?